# Points not filling trying to draw an arrow head (triangle) with Graphics2D

Tags: java, swing, awt, java-2d

When trying to draw an arrowhead using Java `Graphics2D` by using points and inputting the coordinates.

```
    g2.drawLine(xLeft+290, yTop + 80, xLeft+290,yTop + 100); //first arrow
    Polygon arrowHead = new Polygon();
    arrowHead.addPoint(xLeft+290, yTop+140);//firstpoint
    arrowHead.addPoint(xLeft+285, yTop+120);//secondpoint
    arrowHead.addPoint(xLeft+295, yTop+120);//thirdpoint
    g2.fillPolygon(arrowHead);
```

This is my code for drawing the line and the arrowhead, I'm not sure at all of the coordinates are correct but I can't see the shape if it will not appear.

Comment: The code works fine for me. I'd consider looking at the `xLeft` and `yTop` values and make sure that you are actually drawing within a visible range

Comment: The distance between the arrow head and the line itself (line ends at vertical 10, arrow starts at vertical 120) is just as big (20) as the length of the line itself (also 20, going from vertical 80 to vertical 100). Draw the arraw at  `yTop + 100` and `yTop + 120` instead of `yTop + 120` and `yTop +140`

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Is your question *"How to X?"*?  If so, add it as an [edit] to the question.  If not, think of a specific question and do the same (edit).

Comment: @MadProgrammer hi the yLeft and xTop values are both set to 0.0 just as a base point for the diagram which I'm drawing

Comment: @kian5749 Here's the problem, I dumped your code into a simple project and ran it.  So long as I allowed enough area (400+ width/height), I could see the arrow painted.  This means that there is an issue with the implementation, not the code you've presented. So, unless you can provide a [mcve], there is nothing more that anyone can do for